Tortoise-orm. Get all records that have M2M connections with specified identifiers
Is it possible, using the library tortoise-orm, to obtain a list of only those objects that have M2M connections with the listed identifiers, without the need to then further process the received data?
from tortoise import Tortoise, fields, run_async
from tortoise.models import Model


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    id = fields.IntField(pk=True, index=True)


class BaseProp(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name: str = fields.CharField(50, null=False, unique=True)


class Property(BaseProp):
    class Meta:
        table = "properties"

    customs: fields.ManyToManyRelation["Custom"]


class Custom(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        table = "customs"

    short = fields.CharField(50, null=False, unique=True)

    properties: fields.ManyToManyRelation["Property"] = fields.ManyToManyField(
        "models.Property", related_name="customs"
    )


async def make() -> None:
    custom_one = await Custom.create(short="one")
    custom_two = await Custom.create(short="two")

    fine = await Property.create(name="fine")
    light = await Property.create(name="light")
    pink = await Property.create(name="pink")

    await custom_one.properties.add(fine, light, pink)
    await fine.customs.add(custom_two)


async def main() -> None:
    await Tortoise.init(config=TORTOISE_CONFIG)
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

    await make()

    result = await Custom.filter(properties__id__in=[1, 2, 3]).distinct()
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_async(main())

Output:
> [<Custom: 1>, <Custom: 2>]

While expected to receive >[<Custom: 1>].
How to get only those Custom that have all the listed property identifiers at once, and not just mentioned at least once?
I also tried the expression Q:
result = await Custom.filter(
    Q(
        Q(properties__id=1),
        Q(properties__id=2),
        Q(properties__id=3)
    )
).distinct()
print(result)

But this returns an empty list.

Solution:
query = (
    # ? Get everyone who is even mentioned
    Custom.filter(properties__id__in=[1, 2, 3])

    # ? We add a calculated field to each Custom
    # ? instance that counts how many times each
    # ? Custom occurs in the sample, removing duplicates
    .annotate(count=Count("id"))

    # ? Since each Custom now has a count field,
    # ? we leave only those with all the listed properties
    .filter(count=3)
)

result = await query
print(result)

Output:
[<Custom: 1>]

